# LoadScene with Fading C#

Tags: c#, scene, unity-game-engine

I use Unity 5.3.1.
I want change Scene with a fade effect.

Everything is working, but, my new scene "grayed" ... Like this :

> grayed image
>   [image]

Instead of :

> regular image
>   [image]

My fading :

```
public class Fading : MonoBehaviour {


public Texture2D fadeOutTexture;
public float fadeSpeed = 0.8f;

private int drawDepth = -1000;
private float alpha = 1.0f;
private int fadeDir = -1;

void OnGUI()
{
    alpha += fadeDir * fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(alpha);

    GUI.color = new Color(GUI.color.r,GUI.color.g,GUI.color.b, alpha);
    GUI.depth = drawDepth;
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), fadeOutTexture);

}

public float BeginFade(int direction)
{
    Debug.Log("BeginFade");
    fadeDir = direction;
    return fadeSpeed;
}

void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
{
    Debug.Log("wasLoaded");
    BeginFade(-1);
}
```

}

And Mycode who performs my scene :

```
 IEnumerator ChangeLevel()
{
    float fadeTime = GameObject.Find("GM").GetComponent<Fading>().BeginFade(1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(fadeTime);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
}
```

And the call of my ChangeLevel function :

```
 if (other.gameObject.name == "MenuController")
 {
    StartCoroutine(ChangeLevel());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of the lighting bug in Unity 5. It happens a lot when the game level is reloaded.

Go to `Unity>Window>Lighting`, uncheck the `auto` option at the bottom in dialog, then test your game again.

Here's the instruction: [How to disable auto light baking in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0he59.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is your GameObject set as DontDestroyOnLoad?
Also I think you have a logical mistake in your code.
You call WaitForSeconds with the time delivered by BeginFade.
That time is fadeSpeed wich is not the same as the time you wait before the screen is black. 
At the moment your `alpha += fadeDir * fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;` says that every second, add a value of 0.8 to alpha. But Alpha is only completly transparent if it is set to one.

So the actual time should be `1 / fadeSpeed`, I think (1.25s).
Why the screen remains gray I cannot tell you. It should go down unless it is 0.

Now, it is not a good idea to have a component with OnGUI enabled the whole time. Even if it doesn't show something, the fact that your MonoBehavior have a OnGUI method creates a big overhead. Since Unity5 released there are many better way's to do screenfading. Just Google a little bit and you find project's like theese (not tested):

- https://gist.github.com/NovaSurfer/5f14e9153e7a2a07d7c5
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrR_udU2gvs